# Show div if variable contains text

Tags: php, html, css

I want to check if a variable contains either a * or ** and then I want it to show a div based on what is found. I had written the a script which wasn't working.

I've now changed it to use PHP and it's now working:

```
<?php

if (strpos($this->element->product_description, '*') !== false) {
    echo '<div class="asterisk">
    <ul class="asterix">
        <li>* Subject to receipt of payment and print ready artwork or sign off of proofs. Large quantities may require a longer lead time.</li>
        <li>** Custom sizes can be manufactured to order, longer lead times may apply.</li>
    </ul>
</div>';
};
?>
```

Comment: Where do you define this in your is example? Also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. `javascript` [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method with `jQuery` selector

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="asterisk" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="asterix">
            <li>* Subject to receipt of payment and print ready artwork or sign off of proofs. Large quantities may require a longer lead time.</li>
            <li>** Custom sizes can be manufactured to order, longer lead times may apply.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        if ($(".asterisk ul li").text().indexOf('*') > -1) {
            $('.asterisk').css('display', 'block');
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @RustyIngles you were writing php method inside html script tag. That is the issue

Comment: @RustyIngles if this is your expected result, please approve my answer.